# Yii2, error occurs while throwing NotFoundException

Tags: php, yii2

I have a simple code that is running on beforeAction event of my application:

```
'on beforeAction' => function ($event) {
    throw new \yii\web\NotFoundHttpException('The requested page does not exist.');
},
```

I expect it to simply show 404 page of my application, but it throws following error:

```
An Error occurred while handling another error:
exception 'yii\web\NotFoundHttpException' with message 'The requested page does not exist.' in /home/files/www/ucms/config/frontend/config.php:9
Stack trace:
0 [internal function]: {closure}(Object(yii\base\ActionEvent))
1 /home/files/www/ucms/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Component.php(541): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(yii\base\ActionEvent))
2 /home/files/www/ucms/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Module.php(607): yii\base\Component->trigger('beforeAction', Object(yii\base\ActionEvent))
3 /home/files/www/ucms/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Controller.php(139): yii\base\Module->beforeAction(Object(yii\web\ErrorAction))
4 /home/files/www/ucms/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Module.php(455): yii\base\Controller->runAction('error', Array)
5 /home/files/www/ucms/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/web/ErrorHandler.php(85): yii\base\Module->runAction('site/error')
6 /home/files/www/ucms/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/ErrorHandler.php(109): yii\web\ErrorHandler->renderException(Object(yii\web\NotFoundHttpException))
7 [internal function]: yii\base\ErrorHandler->handleException(Object(yii\web\NotFoundHttpException))
8 {main}
Previous exception:
exception 'yii\web\NotFoundHttpException' with message 'The requested page does not exist.' in /home/files/www/ucms/config/frontend/config.php:9
Stack trace:
0 [internal function]: {closure}(Object(yii\base\ActionEvent))
1 /home/files/www/ucms/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Component.php(541): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(yii\base\ActionEvent))
2 /home/files/www/ucms/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Module.php(607): yii\base\Component->trigger('beforeAction', Object(yii\base\ActionEvent))
3 /home/files/www/ucms/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Controller.php(139): yii\base\Module->beforeAction(Object(yii\base\InlineAction))
4 /home/files/www/ucms/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Module.php(455): yii\base\Controller->runAction('', Array)
5 /home/files/www/ucms/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/web/Application.php(84): yii\base\Module->runAction('', Array)
6 /home/files/www/ucms/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Application.php(375): yii\web\Application->handleRequest(Object(yii\web\Request))
7 /home/files/www/ucms/web/index.php(17): yii\base\Application->run()
8 {main}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Problem in `ErrorHandler.php` file on [85 line](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/web/ErrorHandler.php#L85):

```
$result = Yii::$app->runAction($this->errorAction);
```

When `ErrorHandler` try run `ErrorAction`, `NotFoundHttpException` triggered again and `ErrorHandler` just show error message without render.

Solution:

```
public function beforeAction($action)
{
    if(!$action instanceof \yii\web\ErrorAction) {
        throw new \yii\web\NotFoundHttpException('The requested page does not exist.');
    }

    return parent::beforeAction($action);
}
```

---

Previous Answer:
On production server also need setup right environments settings in your `index.php` file:

```
defined('YII_DEBUG') or define('YII_DEBUG', false);
defined('YII_ENV') or define('YII_ENV', 'prod');
```

Comment: Great! :) you are right, it was like a recursion before this fix. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

another fix which helped us was to add this environment variables in the `index.php` :

```
defined('YII_ENABLE_ERROR_HANDLER') or define('YII_ENABLE_ERROR_HANDLER', false);
```